# PyQt - list indices must be integers not str (dictionary)

Tags: python, pyqt4

```
    def SaveUsers( self ):
    Forename = str(self.ui.ForenameEdit.text())
    Surname = str(self.ui.SurnameEdit.text())
    Username = str(self.ui.UsernameEdit.text())
    Password = str(self.ui.PasswordEdit.text())
    PasswordConfirm = str(self.ui.PasswordEdit2.text())
    if self.ui.SecLvlAdminRadio.isChecked() == True:
        SecurityLvl = 'Admin'
    elif self.ui.SecLvlBasicRadio.isChecked() == True:
        SecurityLvl = 'Basic'
    else:
        QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self, 'Error', 'Please choose a security level.')

    Users[Username] = {'Username': Username, 'Password': Password, 'Forename': Forename, 'Surname': Surname, 'Security Level': SecurityLvl}
    print(Users[Username])
    SaveToFile('Users.dat', Users)
    CreateUser.close()
```

Produces the error: *TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str* on the line beginning with Users[Username] = {'Username':...

SaveToFile() is a created subprogram from another module

Please help me fix this or, if there is a better way of going about this please suggest it.

Thanks

Comment: Where did `Users` come from? You don't define it anywhere in this code, so it must be a global variable you defined elsewhere. (Let's ignore the fact that that's probably a bad idea, and it should probably be either a parameter or a member of `self`.) So, if you want to know why it's a list, you're going to have to show us the code that creates it.

Comment: sorry it is defined at the top of the module as Users = []

Comment: Edit the question to include that. A question should have enough information to be answerable as written. People searching for questions to help with don't see comments, nor do people with the same problem as you searching for help. Please read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the rest of the help to see what should go in a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Users` is a list. `Users[n]` is attempting to look up the `nth` element of that list. Therefore `n` must be an integer. You have tried to use a string, which doesn't make sense.

Instead you'll need to make sure that your list index is an integer, like an ID number:

```
UserID = 1
Users[UserID] = {'Username': Username, 'Password': Password, 'Forename': Forename, 'Surname': Surname, 'Security Level': SecurityLvl}
```

Alternatively you could make `Users` a dictionary and then you can assign a dictionary value based on a key that can be a string like you were trying:

```
Users = {}
Users[Username] = {'Username': Username, 'Password': Password, 'Forename': Forename, 'Surname': Surname, 'Security Level': SecurityLvl}
```